# Trying to convert login from mysqli to sqlsrv

Tags: php, mysql, sqlsrv

I am currently trying to convert a php login I have that uses mysql (I know this is a bit dated) to using sqlsrv. This is just a learning task as I wanted to learn to migrate a site from mySQL to MSSQL.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Connect to mysql server
    $serverName = "localhost";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbname", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"123");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
    if( $conn === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return $str;
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $login = clean($_POST['username']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);

    //Input Validations
    if($login == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }

    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$login' AND Password='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $qry );    

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($stmt) {
        $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );
        if($row_count == 1) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = sqlsrv_fetch_assoc($stmt);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['idUsers'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['FirstName'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['LastName'];
            session_write_close();
            header("location: home.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                echo $row['FirstName'];
                $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );
                echo $row_count;
                echo $stmt;
            }
            //Login failed
            //header("location: index.php");
            exit();
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Asset Manager</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/login.css">

</head>


    <header>
        <img src="img/logo.png">        
    </header>

    <ul>

    </ul>


    <div class="main-content">

        <form class="form-login" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">

            <div class="form-log-in-with-email">

                <div class="form-white-background">

                    <div class="form-title-row">
                        <h1>Log in</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label>
                            <span>Username</span>
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label>
                            <span>Password</span>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">Log in</button>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </form>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The issue is it just keeps going to the last else. I have been doing some troubleshooting as you can see in the code. the issue I think is that the rowcount does not work. When I echo ut the row count I just get a Resource 5 showing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to change

```
if($stmt) {
    $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );
    if($row_count == 1) {
```

to:

```
if($stmt) {
    $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows( $stmt );
    if($rows === true) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If project is old and messy, you might consider to write wrapping functions, something like this:

```
function mysql_num_rows($result){
   $rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
   // change $rows in the way you need
   return $rows;
}
```

#### Update

If you have no `mysql` extension, `mysql_num_rows()` will not be available and there will be no problem to define this function.

If you can not remove `mysql` extension, make it `my_mysql_num_rows()` and replace "mysql_" with "my_mysql_".